# What real life applications does diffusion limited aggregation have?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, diffusion, fractals

While studying DLA - diffusion limited aggregation - in the field of fluid dynamics I started wondering what real life application does this phenomena have? We observe fractals in experiments such as following experiment : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf1gR-tNzUs` and pondering that we will be able to explain why the fractals appear in such way, what can we learn from this and how is that applicable in for instance life science or anything related to sustainability or global goals?

The exact problem is :
"The effect of fractal fingering can be observed if a droplet of an ink-alcohol mixture is deposited onto diluted acrylic paint. How are the geometry and dynamics of the fingers influenced by relevant parameters?"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I added the exact problem statement.